# SQL Server - Conversion Failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running a very straightforward bit of SQL and receiving a very strange error with it that I can't seem to explain.

I am getting the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '20.02.01' to data type int.
```

Obviosuly I would be looking for something in my query that is trying to convert an nvarchar value to an int, but as you can see below nothing is doing that!

I can't work out why this would be happening.

Please help!

```
SELECT  R.ReservationsID,
        R.CollectionCompanyName,
        R.CollectionCompanyAddress1,
        R.CollectionCompanyAddress2,
        R.CollectionCompanyTown,
        R.CollectionCompanyPostCode,
        R.DeliveryCompanyName,
        R.DeliveryCompanyAddress1,
        R.DeliveryCompanyAddress2,
        R.DeliveryCompanyTown,
        R.DeliveryCompanyPostCode,
        R.[DeliveryCompanyTel No],
        hw.WasteName,
        hw.WasteTicket,
        hw.SizeName,
        hw.Comments,
        hw.QTY,
        hw.OriginalOrderQty,
        hw.gross,
        hw.tare,
        hw.Net,
        C.PremisesCode,
        pec.EwcCode,
        pec.[Description] 'EWC Desc',
        RI.SICCode,
        lwt.WCode  'EWC',
        R.ActualDeliveryTime,
        R.ActualDeliveryDate



FROM
tblReservation R
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblHazLinesWaste hw ON hw.resid = r.ReservationsID
LEFT JOIN dbo.PdaEwcCode pec ON pec.HazCodeID = hw.EWCCodeID
LEFT JOIN tblCustomer C ON C.CustomerID = R.CustomerID 
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblReservationItems RI ON RI.reservationsID = R.ReservationsID
LEFT JOIN dbo.lookupWasteTypes lwt ON lwt.WCode = RI.EWCCodeID

WHERE
hw.Deleted != 1
```

Comment: Check your table definitions, do all the ID fls have the same data types? In effect is the reservation ID as string and the hw.resid as bigint or uid?

Comment: Omg put that as an answer and I'll accept, I know what's wrong.

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Comment: yes, the only part where it could happen is the ON part of the JOIN, where an expression is used...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your table definitions, do all the ID fls have the same data types? In effect is the reservation ID as string and the hw.resid as bigint or uid?

Comment: Yep - LEFT JOIN dbo.lookupWasteTypes lwt ON lwt.WCode = RI.EWCCodeID was the issue, thanks I just didn't spot it. Will accept in 10 minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score -1):

You've got single quotes for field names: `pec.[Description] 'EWC Desc',` and `lwt.WCode  'EWC',`.  Those should be double quotes.  Single quotes are for string literals.

Beyond that, check your data types for the fields in your `ON` clauses and the `WHERE` clause where you're comparing fields.

Comment: Syntactically single quotes are fine for aliasing columns.

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid Ah, you're right. I guess I just go back and forth between SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and Oracle so I just avoid using that syntax. Oracle syntax (and therefore PostgreSQL syntax) doesn't let you do that.